# How to create a list and append values as in python using lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am trying to create a list with filename from my local directory and add that to http request body in nginx using lua. something like below

```
filelist = [] #a list variable to hold the filenames
for file in f:lines() do
   #file i get my filename one by one
   filelist.append(file)
end

request_payload = {"somedata":"its key", "files": filelist}
```

assuming i have the request body and i need to update that json with the new filelist variable value.

I know with lua there is nothing like list object instead it have table structure. But is there any easy hacks to get this done

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with lua arrays

```
local filelist = {} #lua table object
for file in f:lines() do
   #file i get my filename one by one
   table.insert(filelist, file) #this will update the array
end
```

Hope that helps someone :)